# Mutt new email status message force show

Tags: email, imap, mutt

I am using mutt with remote gmail account where have gmail labels/folders as mutt `mailboxes`.  When I am in some folder and mutt synchronizes it says in status:

```
 `You have new email in =Debian/Devel and ...`
```

Is there a way to show this message on demand? Not only with the first sync ? After is disappears I cannot show it again. I would like to know where are new emails. Hitting `$` does not solve this problem, so it does not `imap-fetch-mail`.

Alternatively maybe there is a way to set status message with a script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently, showing this message again can be triggered by pressing `.` which is bound to `buffy-list` command.

If you want to have a script shown in status message, one needs to pipe output of the script into a `status-format`.